# How to determine what type of function when there are multiple types

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^3-1}}{1+\sqrt[3]{x}}$$

This equation has 3 different types of expressions namely, exponential, rational, and root. How do I determine what type of function this is?

Comment: thank you for the edit. Where can I look for displaying the right symbols on a post?

Comment: mixed function,...isn't it?

Comment: For symbols and much much more see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The question only leaves one option between power, root, poly, rational, algebraic, trig, exponential, or log function.

Comment: Thank you David. Also, after writing my last comment... I think it might be algebraic...

Answer (score 1):

Most functions don't have a "type".  We give names to certain special types of functions that are useful to categorize (such as polynomials), but there's no particularly commonly named "type" that this function falls into.  At best, we can say that it is an [algebraic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function), but most people wouldn't bother categorizing it at all (as "algebraic functions" are not very often a useful category).

Comment: In fact, I think most of the introductory phases of university education is pointless because it's so far removed from application and real world practice.